# PHP currency formatting (moneyFormat) adding 0s before the decimal place when using locale other then en_US

Tags: php, localization, locale, php-5.3, money-format

I have a value like 119.00 stored as a float.

I am formatting it with moneyFormat("%.2n", 119.00).

When I format it in US I get the correct result: $119.00

When I format it with anything else (ex. es_MX.UTF-8) it adds 2 extra zeros before the decimal place: $11,900.00.

Is there something more I need to configure somewhere?

This is on a linux machine (centos 6) with php 5.3.

Edit:
I discovered that a call to setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, "es_MX.UTF-8") was causing this.  I dont know why though.  It should only affect the format of the number (ie. a comma instead of a period, etc.), but it seems to be altering the actual value.